# Integrate $\int \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^3}}dx$ with substitution?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

> I really struggle with integrating integrals such as: $\displaystyle\int \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^3}}dx$

I know it should be something substitution, but I don't know how exactly to do so. I struggle with the fact that I have power of $3$ in the fraction.

How should I continue?

Comment: This one is already very difficult. It involves elliptic integrals.

Comment: What makes you think that there is a simple answer?

Comment: For what it's worth, Mathematica yields an answer using the hypergeometric functions: $$\int\frac{x\,dx}{\sqrt{1+x^3}}=\frac{1}{2} x^2 \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3};\frac{5}{3};-x^3\right).
 $$

Comment: Integrals easily done by substitution include $\displaystyle\int \frac{x\,dx}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$ and $\displaystyle\int \frac{x^2\,dx}{\sqrt{1+x^3}}$, but not the one you propose.

Comment: Substitution will not work well because the derivative of $x^3$ is $x^2$ (coefficient omitted), which does not match the $x$ at the numerator.

Comment: There is one result about it by Chebyshev. https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Chebyshev_theorem_on_the_integration_of_binomial_differentials

Comment: It exactly proves, that you can't express this in elementary functions.

Comment: thank you very much! and, well, I though this was easy since I found it in an openstax calculus II book, so I just assumed it was a me problem :)